# The DirectRender library could not be found

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, directx

I'm programming on Windows 7 in Visual Studio 2010 C++ with camera hardware from some company...

I am using their libraries and I am getting an Error in the `SetDisplayMode()` function when I try to set Direct3D mode.

The program can see it (DIRECT3D macro), because the wisper give me advice to this param, so I have included this library OK.

The error is

```
"The DirectRender library could not be found"
```

This is error code from their library, not from my c++ compiler.

Can anyone help me solve this problem? I can't seem to find anything about this error, where I can get the library, whats wrong,etc.

I cant look into their library code, maybe because the libraries are .lib and .dll.

My graphic card provides OpenGL and Direct3D both...

Comment: If you have a problem with a library, you should ask the developer of the library...

Comment: not sure how to help if you do not even mention which library you are using.

Comment: `I cant look into their library code`: but surely you can look at the documentation or ask the developer of the library?

Comment: Licence between me and the provider is OK, its totally legally. It is camera from Thorlabs and I was chating to them,and they said that I should send them my code..I done it and I dont have the responce for 4 days. But I think this is problem in my computer,not in their libraries =/ I use uc480.h library with uc480.dll and uc480.lib...And I cant find the solution in the text documentation...there is their funkcion,how to set params,etc...no the whole code =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether or not the the library you're talking about was statically built with D3D but i'm assuming that its not. The important thing is that you have the Direct3D runtime installed. Judging by the info you gave, it seems like you don't. If that library wants to call a dynamic library and doesn't find it, you aren't necessarily going to get a compiler/Linker error.

Here's a link to the runtime: [DirectX End-User Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35)

Also, .lib and .dll are just byte code to be linked statically and dynamically respectively. Its normal that you cannot generate or access c++ code from them.

Comment: yeees, Thanks for the link Joseph Pla...Problem solved. I have reinstalled DirectX drivers and it works great now... but I had to reinstall cameras drivers too,dunno why, but my PC couldnt detect the kamera... Thaaanks!

Comment: I cant only understand why other applications worked great but this one not :-)